# Change 'Ingress traffic' setting for Azure Container Application through Bicep deployment

Tags: azure, containers, azure-cloud-services, azure-bicep

I am trying to connect to an [Azure Container App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/container-apps) (not an Azure Container Instance!) which is deployed using the following Bicep deployment scripts:

## vnet

```
resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetAddressPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: subnetName
        properties: {
          privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
          addressPrefix: vnetAddressPrefix
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## appEnv

```
resource appEnv 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-10-01' = {
  name: containerAppEnvName
  location: location
  properties: {
    vnetConfiguration: {
      infrastructureSubnetId: vnet.properties.subnets[0].id
      internal: false
    }
    zoneRedundant: false
  }
}
```

## containerApp

```
resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-10-01' = {
  name: containerAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    environmentId: appEnv.id
    configuration: {
      secrets: [
        {
          name: 'password'
          value: '...'
        }
      ]      
      registries: [
        {
          server: '...'
          username: '...'
          passwordSecretRef: 'password'
        } 
      
      ]
      ingress: {
        external: true
        targetPort: 7687
        exposedPort: 7687
        transport: 'tcp'
      }
    }
    template: {
      containers: [
        {
          image: '...'
          name: 'neo4j'
          env: []
          resources: {
            cpu: 2
            memory: '4Gi'
          }
        }
      ]
      scale: {
        minReplicas: 1
        maxReplicas: 1
      }
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    vnet
  ]
}
```

This all succeeds: all resources are successfully created in the Azure Portal. However, if I try to connect to the Azure Container App, I get a generic ServiceUnavailable error:

```
[error] session error - ServiceUnavailable: Neo4jError: WebSocket connection failure. ...
```

When I look up the Container App in the Azure Portal and select the `Ingress` blade, I see this:

[image]

I'd like to try and select the option `Accept traffic from anywhere`<sup>1</sup> (the red arrow in the screenshot), but that cannot be selected. In the Bicep documentation, I cannot find a parameter `internalOnly` for a Container App Environment (changing `internal: ...` in `vnetConfiguration` does not work).

Question: how can I change the Bicep deployment script(s) so that `Accept traffic from anywhere` is selected?

<sup>1</sup> we're in a POC-like phase, so security is not top-priority for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully set up a container app with public TCP ingress. The setting responsible for `Accept traffic from anywhere` is on the container environment (`vnetConfiguration.internal` must be `false`). However I needed to delete and recreate the environment after changing this to false to actually get the desired change.

This was my bicep template:

```
resource logAnalytics 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2020-10-01' = {
  name: logname
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: 'PerGB2018'
    }
  }
}

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  name: vnetname
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.10.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'helloworld'
        properties: {
          privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
          addressPrefix: '10.10.0.0/16'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource containerAppEnv 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-03-01' = {
  name: containerappenv
  location: location
  properties: {
    appLogsConfiguration: {
      destination: 'log-analytics'
      logAnalyticsConfiguration: {
        customerId: logAnalytics.properties.customerId
        sharedKey: logAnalytics.listKeys().primarySharedKey
      }
    }
    vnetConfiguration: {
      infrastructureSubnetId: vnet.properties.subnets[0].id
      internal: false
    }
  }
}

resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-10-01' = {
  name: containerappname
  location: location
  properties: {
    managedEnvironmentId: containerAppEnv.id
    configuration: {
      ingress: {
        external: true
        targetPort: targetPort
        exposedPort: 3000
        transport: 'tcp'
        allowInsecure: false
        traffic: [
          {
            latestRevision: true
            weight: 100
          }
        ]
      }
      registries: [
        {
            server: registry
            identity: identity
        }
      ]
    }
    template: {
      revisionSuffix: 'secondrevision'
      containers: [
        {
          name: ...
          image: containerImage
          resources: {
            cpu: json(cpuCore)
            memory: '${memorySize}Gi'
          }
        }
      ]
      scale: {
        minReplicas: minReplicas
        maxReplicas: maxReplicas
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I must've started with `internal: true` and later changed it to `internal: false`. After deleting the App Environment and then letting it be created by the bicep template again did the trick! Many thanks!

Comment: I can only award the bounty after another 14 hours, which I will do so tomorrow.